# Angular translate - When multiple loader it execute only the last one

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I've got a project using angular translate with a custom loader.
Basically, this is the config in my provider (which is working perfectly).

**Provider (stuff executed in the config of my app)**

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');
$translateProvider.useLoader('componentsTranslationLoader');
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage($language);
```

As you can see, I use my own componentsTranslationLoader. It does the stuff as expected.

**Factory (componentsTranslationLoader)**

```
return function(options) {
        var deferred     = $q.defer();
        var translations = {};

        $http.get('languages/components/' + options.key + '.json').success(function(keys) {
            translations = keys;
            deferred.resolve(translations);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
};
```

Everythings is fine from here.

---

I have to use a library in this project (company's one, I can edit it), and this library also has his own angular translate stuff (basically the same thing).
It has a custom loader, initialized into the config.

When my project is executed, I expect that both loader do their stuff and extend the language with their keys.
It didn't.
Only the last loader is executed (see it with logs).

So, how can I resolve this conflict properly please ?
Is there something wrong with my way of using angular translate ?
Thanks for the help guys.

**Edit (more informations added)**
I added more call like this one into the config with different 'fake' loader:

```
$translateProvider.useLoader('aFakeLoaderWithLogs');
```

And the problem still the same, only the last one into the config is called.
I searched for topics with similar issues and found nothing, even in the documentation.

Comment: Should I start a bounty ? :-)

Comment: I solved your issue. Check it my answer and you can mark it as correct, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach of merging responses. Works for me very well.

```
function customLoader($http, $q, localeUrl, errorCodeUrl) {

    return  function (options) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var translations = [];

        $q.all([
            $http.get(localeUrl + "locale-" + options.key +".json"),
            $http.get(errorCodeUrl + "?lang=cs")
        ]).then(function(response, status) {
            translations.push(response[0].data);
            translations.push(response[1].data);
            console.log(translations);
            deferred.resolve(translations);
            return translations;
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
}
```